# How to replace the alert message box with RadWindow

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

My Code:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="UpdateFavoriteRadWindow" Width="300" Height="150" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" CssClass="radwindow" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div align="center" class="addFavoriteborder">
            <br /><br />
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateFavorite" runat="server" Text="Changes Updated"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>

protected void btnUpdateReport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // code to update
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Changes Updated')</script>"); // how to replace this message box with RadWindow
}
```

I want to show the RadWindow instead of alert message box. Thanks

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: @PranayRana, I tried with UpdateFavoriteRadWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = True. It works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

RAD Alert box

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      RadWindowManager windowManager = 
               FindControl(this, "WindowManager") as RadWindowManager;
   windowManager.RadAlert("MessageText", 400, null, "title", null);                   
  }
```

More detail : [Open RadWindow on Button Click Event](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/open-radwindow-on-button-click-event.aspx)

For more details you check this discussion on RAD site : http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/problem-with-radwindows-confirm-and-alert.aspx

Comment: The name 'window' does not exist in the current context msg is displayed. Thanks

Comment: @SOUser - you can check my edited answer as well as link of the answer that will help you..

Comment: I tried with UpdateFavoriteRadWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = True. Needed places, I make it to false. It works fine. I will try your solution.Thanks.

Comment: Or generally here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx