# Validating a row in grid view and show message

Tags: c#, validation, silverlight, telerik, radwindow

I am using telerik controls only.
I am validating a row and if the validation fails on certain condition.I need to open the radwindow and show the message to the user saying there is some error.

```
private void radGridViewHolidays_RowValidating(object sender, GridViewRowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
   if (condition )
        {
           e.valid=false;
           Radwindow.Alert("error message");
         }
    }
```

When I execute the above code the `radwindow` flickers and I cant close the window nor can I change the value in the grid.

My issue is:
When the validation fails the row gets the focus and at the same time I need to show the error message to  the user.

When I use a `messagebox.show()`, it works fine. I need to use only the telerik control(Radwindow)to achieve this.

Comment: sounds like you need to check out the Telerik Radwindow.Alert they have samples out there on their site.. also why don't you just use basick JavaScript...? also why do you only need to use Telerik..there are many ways to skin this cat.. and since you're too lazy to do a simple google search here is a good link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909701/how-to-replace-the-alert-message-box-with-radwindow please show more effort Merry XMAS

Comment: @k If I could have. I would have done it.I need to do it using Radwindow only.Read the question.

Answer (score 0):

an object, that represents the content and an event handler that should handle the Closed event of the RadWindow.

```
private void radGridViewHolidays_RowValidating(object sender, GridViewRowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
   if (condition )
        {
           e.valid=false;
           Radwindow.Alert("error message", this.OnClosed);
         }
    }
```

try like this

```
private void OnClosed( object sender, WindowClosedEventArgs e )
{
    RadWindowManager.Current.CloseAllWindows();
}
```

C#

```
RadWindowManager1.RadAlert("An <br /><b>html</b> string.<br />", 200, 100);
```

Note:The appearance of the alert dialog is controlled by two things: the Skin property of the RadWindowManager, and the values you pass in as arguments to RadAlert. The arguments can include the HTML string you pass in as a message, the width, the height, and the Title string.

[For more info](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-dialogs-alert.html)

Comment: @ I need it for silverlight and I can't make my own window.I need to use a existing window that is consistent in the application.

Comment: @user2526236 Have you add the namespace?

Comment: @ Midhun I cant have another window of my own just for this scenario. I need to use existing radwindow as the window remains consistent through out the app.

Comment: @ midhun Its not working. Using `radwindow.alert()` I have only one button.OK button which should close the window is not happening.

Comment: @ midhun  can I close the window on the OK button click.

Comment: yes using ok Event handler you can achieve this http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/E_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadAlert_Ok.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67641/discussion-between-user2526236-and-midhun-mundayadan).

Comment: I just want to close the window on the click of OK button.

Comment: RadWindow.Confirm( "Are you sure?", this.OnClosed ); you can use like this

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radwindow/features/predefined-dialogs